# PHP Paypal plus Integrate Pay upon Invoice

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I integrated Paypal Plus in my page and everything worked well in "Sandbox" mode, now I changed the mode to "live" and the `Pay upon Invoice` selection in my Payment wall somehow disappeared.

My js code for Payment wall is

```
var ppp = PAYPAL.apps.PPP({
        "approvalUrl": "<?=$approvalUrl?>",
        "placeholder": "ppplus",
        "mode": "live",
        "country": "DE",
        "language": "de_DE",
        useraction: "commit",
        buttonLocation: "outside"
```

I'm little bit confused about this whole Invoice thing... do I have to change something in my PHP code to use it or do I actually have to create an `new Invoice()` instead of `new payment()`? Until now I just created a new Payment() and filled all information (prices, shipping adress) into it and used the approval_url to render the payment wall. Where is my error?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I guess that "pay upon invoice" is not unlocked by paypal for your account. You have to apply for it.